# how to do secondary sort in SparkSteaming

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I was using the way mentioned [here](http://codingjunkie.net/spark-secondary-sort/) to do secondary sorting in Spark-Streaming. But it gives the following error :

```
repartitionAndSortWithinPartitions is not a member of org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream
```

**Code :**

```
def ProcessDStream(lines : DStream[EventData]) {            
            val dataSetrawSorted = lines.repartitionAndSortWithinPartitions(new DataSetPartitioner(1000))
            }
```

So, how to achieve the same in Dstream.

Answer (score 0):

Use transform:

```
stream.transform { rdd => rdd.repartitionAndSortWithinPartitions(...) }
```

Comment: I am getting this error while applying the above syntax `value repartitionAndSortWithinPartitions is not a member of org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD`